# SpringBoot gradle plugin complains "Unresolved reference: providedRuntime"

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm following the latest [SpringBoot gradle plugin reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-wars-deployable) in order to setup a SpringBoot project that can build a uberjar.

Below is the full content of `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    java
    application
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.testng:testng:6.14.3")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = "com.demo.App"
}

val test by tasks.getting(Test::class) {
    // Use TestNG for unit tests
    useTestNG()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run gradle commands I get the following error:

```
> Configure project :
e: /Users/xux/Documents/toys/web/build.gradle.kts:15:5: Unresolved reference: providedRuntime

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/xux/Documents/toys/web/build.gradle.kts' line: 15

* What went wrong:
Script compilation error:

  Line 15:     providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
               ^ Unresolved reference: providedRuntime

1 error
```

I'm using Java 1.8.0_201, Gradle 6.0, Kotlin 1.3.50, Mac OS X 10.15.1 x86_64.

Comment: `providedRuntime` is a configuration exposed by the Gradle `war` plugin (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_dependency_management) . You need to apply this plugin in your build script (default behavior with Springboot Gradle plugin is to produce executable `jar`, not `war)

Comment: I just need a uberjar, it works without `providedRuntime`. Thanks @M.Ricciuti!